# Finding vectors in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have two vectors of `vector<unsigned>` namely: `vector<vector<unsigned> > sbp, vector<vector<unsigned> > sp`. I want to print all those vectors in sbp which are also in `sp`. Both vectors `sbp` and `sp` are stored (i) first by size; (ii) and when the size are equal, then the vectors are sorted lexicographically. I wrote the following code for doing the same. The code appears to be giving segmentation fault. I debugged the code (by printing out values), but I am not able to find the source of the error.

Can someone please help me find what could be the source of segmentation fault. Also if there is some algorithm which is faster than this, then that will be really great

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<vector<unsigned> > sbp;
    vector<vector<unsigned> > sp;
    vector<vector<unsigned> >::iterator itSP=sp.begin();   
    for(vector<vector<unsigned> >::iterator itSbp=sbp.begin(),lSbp=sbp.end();itSbp!=lSbp;)
    {
        if(std::lexicographical_compare(((*itSbp)).begin(), ((*itSbp)).end(), (*itSP).begin(), (*itSP).end()))
        {
            itSbp++;
        }else{
            if((*itSbp)==(*itSP)) 
            {
              //  cout<<(*itSbp)<<"\n";
                itSbp++;
            }else{
                itSP++;                
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

I am using C++11(gcc 4.8)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz it is set here lSbp=sbp.end()

Comment: does [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/769e412f10ce39bb) even compile?

Comment: @MarcoA. now it should

Comment: @DavidSchwartz it seems that it's set in the for loop (coma operator for the init list)

Comment: @StegVerner If the inner vectors are compared on both size and order, then the `std::set_intersection` algorithm does all of this work.  See here: http://ideone.com/ydSqmE

Comment: can't reproduce the problem...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks. Both sbp and sp vector's are huge..is it possible to save some space as "result" is going to consume some space. If yes, how?

Comment: @StegVerner  How large is "huge"?  Anyway, if there are duplicates, you can use `std::set` as the resulting container.  This makes sure that you store only vectors that are unique in size and data.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to print all those vectors in sbp which are also in sp.

Whenever there is a situation where you want to collate the common values that are in two containers, the algorithm that should spring to mind right away is [`std::set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection).

The caveat is that `std::set_intersection` requires that the containers contain sorted values (or a functor provided that describes the sort order).  However, if you can meet that criteria, then the solution is trivial.

Here is an example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // test data
    vector<vector<unsigned> > sbp = { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7 }, { 1, 2, 3, 6, 7 }, { 2, 3, 4, 6, 7 }};
    vector<vector<unsigned> > sp = { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7 }, { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8 }, { 2, 3, 4, 6, 7 }};

    // resulting vector
    vector<vector<unsigned> > result;

    // get the intersection of the two values
    set_intersection(sbp.begin(), sbp.end(), sp.begin(), sp.end(), back_inserter(result));

    // output the results
    for_each(result.begin(), result.end(), [](const std::vector<unsigned>& v) 
            {copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<unsigned>(cout, " ")); cout << "\n";});
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/ydSqmE)

If the number of items are large, and there is a good possibility that the data contains duplicates, then a `std::set` can be used to store the data.

```
    // resulting vector
    std::set<vector<unsigned>> result;

    // get the intersection of the two values
    set_intersection(sbp.begin(), sbp.end(), sp.begin(), sp.end(), std::inserter(result, result.begin()));
```